# How to deploy react Remix framework to IIS on windows server 2022?

Tags: iis, deployment, remix.run, windows-server-2022

I developed an App on REMIX framework. But ı do not know how will i publish it on IIS server on Windows Server 2022.
Which opitons should selected for IIS.

```
 npx create-remix@latest
 ? Where would you like to create your app? (./my-remix-app)
 ? Where do you want to deploy? Choose Remix if you're unsure, it's easy to change deployment targets. (Use arrow keys)
❯ Remix App Server
? TypeScript or JavaScript? (Use arrow keys)
❯ TypeScript
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answers which showed me a way for found a solition.

1. Install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) on Windows Server .
2. Install [IIS Node](https://github.com/azure/iisnode/releases/download/v0.2.21/iisnode-full-v0.2.21-x64.msi) on Windows Server.
3. Install [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) on Windows Server.
4. Upload all files to under your web site folder on wwwroot except .cache,build,public/build,node_modules folders.(we will install them on server.)
5. Under web site folder, type command on cmd `npm install`
6. Type command `npm run dev`
7. Create a web.config file main path of web site. Codes are :

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration> 
   <system.webServer>
   <iisnode loggingEnabled="false" nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" />        
   <handlers>
   <add name="iisnode" path="/build/index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
   </handlers>  
   <security>
   <requestFiltering>
    <hiddenSegments>
      <add segment="node_modules" />
      <add segment="iisnode" />
    </hiddenSegments>
    </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <rewrite>
       <rules>
           <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url="(.*)" />
               <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:1}" />
           </rule>
       </rules>
   </rewrite>
   </system.webServer> 
   </configuration>
   ```

Comment: This would run the application in development mode on IIS.

Answer (score 2):

The best way for the React Remix framework is to select **Remix App Server**, then run `remix build` to build the app for production, and run `npm start` to run the server. After performing the above operations, please treat it as a normal Node.js server, and follow the Conventional Way - deploying a node.js application on windows IIS using a reverse proxy.

1. Install Node.js on Windows Server
2. Deploy and test Node.js applications
3. Create a website for our Node.js application on IIS
4. Configure Reverse Proxy on IIS

Answer (score 1):

Remix requires Node.js when running on Windows. You should select *Remix App Server*.

There are plenty of articles online on how to set up a reverse proxy on IIS. You want to proxy to RAS running on localhost:3000 (by default).

https://www.google.com/search?q=iis+nodejs+reverse+proxy