# How do I Deploy Remix App on Windows IIS shared hosting

Tags: remix.run

I want to deploy a Remix app on a Windows IIS Server. There have been answers to this question here - [How to deploy react Remix framework to IIS on windows server 2022?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75049232/)

However, this requires the server to be logged in. If I'm using a VPS Server that is possible. But how do I deploy to a shared hosting, for example, where I cannot run npm? Assumming I have IIS node installed on the shared hosting website, how do I deploy a Remix build?

A create-react-app webiste can be easily deployed by just copying the dist folder to the server.

When I build a remix app. I get a public/build folder. How do I deploy this folder to a public IIS website.

Thanks